# To check if a file is written completely

Tags: java, file, process, runtime

How do I know if a software is done writing a file if I am executing that software from java?For example, I am executing geniatagger.exe with an input file RawText that will produce an output file TAGGEDTEXT.txt. When geniatagger.exe is finished writing the TAGGEDTEXT.txt file, I can do some other staffs with this file. The problem is- how can I know that geniatagger is finished writing the text file?

```
try{
  Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = rt.exec("geniatagger.exe -i "+ RawText+ " -o TAGGEDTEXT.txt");
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't `.exec()` block until whatever you're execing complets and exits?

Comment: No mark, it invokes geniatagger.exe- that is alright, but the program control goes to the next block of code straight away (while geniatagger.exe is still writing the TAGGEDTEXT.txt)

Comment: Does the program exit after it finishes writing the file?  Can you parse the file to determine when it is complete?  How do you know when the program is done writing the file?

Comment: Normally, when I am running geniatagger.exe outside from java then TAGGEDTEXT.txt is created first and then the parsed texts are inserted into it (the file size increases... increases... and stops) @maerics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, or at least not reliably.

In this particular case your best bet is to watch the Process complete.

You get the process' return code as a bonus, this could tell you if an error occurred.

If you are actually talking about [this GENIA tagger](http://www-tsujii.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/GENIA/tagger/), below is a practical example which demonstrates various topics (see explanation about numbered comments beneath the code). The code was tested with v1.0 for Linux and demonstrates how to safely run a process which expects both input and output stream piping to work correctly.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class GeniaTagger {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tagFile(new File("inputText.txt"), new File("outputText.txt"));
    }

    public static void tagFile(File input, File output) {
        FileInputStream ifs = null;
        FileOutputStream ofs = null;
        try {
            ifs = new FileInputStream(input);
            ofs = new FileOutputStream(output);
            final FileInputStream ifsRef = ifs;
            final FileOutputStream ofsRef = ofs;

            // {1}    
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("geniatagger.exe");
            final Process pr = pb.start();

            // {2}
            runInThread(new Callable<Void>() {
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    IOUtils.copy(ifsRef, pr.getOutputStream());
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(pr.getOutputStream());   // {3}
                    return null;
                }
            });
            runInThread(new Callable<Void>() {
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    IOUtils.copy(pr.getInputStream(), ofsRef);   // {4}
                    return null;
                }
            });
            runInThread(new Callable<Void>() {
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    IOUtils.copy(pr.getErrorStream(), System.err);
                    return null;
                }
            });

            // {5}
            pr.waitFor();
            // output file is written at this point.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // {6}
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(ifs);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(ofs);
        }
    }

    public static void runInThread(final Callable<?> c) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    c.call();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

1. Use a `ProcessBuilder` to start your process, it has a better interface than plain-old `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)`.
2. Set up stream piping in different threads, otherwhise the `waitFor()` call in ({5}) might never complete.
3. Note that I piped a `FileInputStream` to the process. According to the afore-mentioned GENIA page, this command expects actual input instead of a `-i` parameter. The `OutputStream` which connects to the process must be closed, otherwhise the program will keep running!
4. Copy the result of the process to a `FileOutputStream`, the result file your are waiting for.
5. Let the main thread wait until the process completes.
6. Clean up all streams.

Comment: Superb! I think the previous solution works for many other exe files... but this one is particularly for genia pos tagger. Learning a lot from you guys. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the program exits after generating the output file then you can call [`Process.waitFor()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) to let it run to completion then you can process the file.  Note that you will likely have to drain both the standard output and error streams (at least on Windows) for the process to finish.

**[Edit]**

Here is an example, untested and likely fraught with problems:

```
  // ...
  Process p = rt.exec("geniatagger.exe -i "+ RawText+ " -o TAGGEDTEXT.txt");
  drain(p.getInputStream());
  drain(p.getErrorStream());
  int exitCode = p.waitFor();
  // Now you should be able to process the output file.
}

private static void drain(InputStream in) throws IOException {
  while (in.read() != -1);
}
```

Comment: The program exits and I tried to use Process.waitFor(). But the system is halted and no output file is created and when I stop the java program, then geniatagger.exe creates the output file.

Comment: You need to drain stdout and stderr from the process.

Comment: @maerics Actually, stream draining should happen in another thread. Your solution might work most of the time, but will block when the process decides to flood stderr and closes the stderr stream before stdout. Using some Apache Commons class likely avoids this issue.

Comment: @JBert: yes, quite true, just wanted to illustrate the simplest thing that could possibly work.

Comment: @maerics, the program control does not move to- // Now you should be able to process the output file.

Comment: @RushdiShams If you are talking about running [the GENIA tagger](http://www-tsujii.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/GENIA/tagger/), things get ridiculously complicated for what appears to be a simple thing. I've edited my answer with sample code and tested with Linux version 1.0.